# React Native, unable to scroll flatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a flatList but it's not scrolling, I'm just rendering it inside View, below is code. I tried to remove View and just render it inside if else but still not scrolling Can some please tell me why it's not scrolling

```
else {
      return (
        <View>
          {!this.state.isClicked ? (
            <FlatList
              style={{marginTop: moderateScaleVertical(10)}}
              numColumns={1}
              data={this.state.industry}
              keyExtractor={(industry) => industry.id.toString()}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <SurveyCard
                  topText={item.topText}
                  time={item.time}
                  title={item.title}
                  date={item.date}
                  price={item.price}
                  off={item.off}
                  image={item.image}
                  progress={item.progress}
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(item.onPress)}
                />
              )}
            />
          ) : (
            <FlatList
              style={styles.industry}
              data={this.state.industry}
              key={this.state.horizontal ? 'h' : 'v'}
              numColumns={2}
              keyExtractor={(industry) => industry.id.toString()}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <SurveyCardRow
                  topText={item.topText}
                  time={item.time}
                  title={item.title}
                  date={item.date}
                  price={item.price}
                  off={item.off}
                  image={item.image}
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(item.onPress)}
                />
              )}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Share a snack link please

Comment: What is the purpose of using multiple flat list? can you please share the SurveyCardRow.